# Somar array multidimensional PHP

Tags: php, array, soma

Bom dia, tenho o seguinte array:

```
Array (  [0] => Array(  [data] => 2018-06-08
                        [grupo] => 1 
                        [maq] => 1
                        [segundos] => 10089 ) 
         [1] => Array ( [data] => 2018-06-08 
                        [grupo] => 1 
                        [maq] => 2 
                        [segundos] => 6300 ) 
        [2] => Array  ( [data] => 2018-06-08 
                        [grupo] => 1 
                        [maq] => 1 
                        [segundos] => 3600 ) 
        [3] => Array (  [data] => 2018-06-09
                        [grupo] => 1
                        [maq] => 1 
                        [segundos] => 3600 ) )
```

Minha dúvida é a seguinte, como posso somar somente a key[segundos], onde a key [data] e [maq] foram a mesma (repetir), como o seguinte output:

```
 Array (  [0] => Array( [data] => 2018-06-08
                        [grupo] => 1 
                        [maq] => 1
                        [segundos] => 13689 ) 
         [1] => Array ( [data] => 2018-06-08 
                        [grupo] => 1 
                        [maq] => 2 
                        [segundos] => 6300 ) 
        [2] => Array (  [data] => 2018-06-09
                        [grupo] => 1
                        [maq] => 1 
                        [segundos] => 3600 ) )
```

Answer (score 0):

Consegui com o seguinte código:

```
$second_array = array_reduce($first_array, function($carry, $item) {
    $key = sprintf('%s-%s', $item['data'], $item['maq']);
    if (isset($carry[$key])) {
        $carry[$key]['segundos'] += $item['segundos'];
    } else {
        $carry[$key] = $item;
    }
    return $carry;
});


$second_array = array_values($second_array);
```